# MVC ActionLink Odd Routing Behavior -- adding link to the end of my current page after hash #

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, actionlink

I must have a configuration set wrong somewhere.

I start out on this page:

```
http://localhost:58982/Game/Score
```

...and click on this link:

```
<a href="/Game/Score/1">Round 1</a>
```

... which resolves to this url

```
http://localhost:58982/Game/Score#/Game/Score/1
```

The browser does not refresh and it adds my link to the end.
What am I doing wrong?

VB.NET RAZR -- both links produce the same results

```
@Html.RouteLink("Round 1", New With {.id = 1})
@Html.ActionLink("Round 1", "Score", New With {.id = 1})
```

Here's the code in my GameController

```
<NoCache()> _
Function Score(Optional ByVal id As Integer = Nothing) As ActionResult
    If id = 0 Then id = 1
    Dim games = (From q In db.Games Where q.RoundId = id)
    Dim rounds = (From q In db.Games Where q.OccasionId = _OccasionId Select q.RoundId).Distinct
    ViewBag.Round = id
    ViewBag.Rounds = rounds
    ViewBag.SessionTeam = SessionTeam
    Return View(games)
End Function
```

Here's how my routes are configured:

```
Public Class RouteConfig
    Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapRoute( _
            name:="Default", _
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class WebApiConfig
    Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="DefaultApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you show us how your routes are configured?

Comment: I updated the original post to include routing config